# if body has a class remove on scroll native javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, scroll, window, removeclass

I'm trying to use native javascript, so no jquery is loaded. I want to make an if statement to **remove** a class in the **body** element only if it has a class. This way I would avoid it to trigger every time there is a scroll. I basically want it to remove the class only if the window is scrolling and the body has this class applied to it, else it should not trigger.

I tried with this code and it does remove the class, but it's always triggering on scroll, no matter if body has a class or not applied to it. In this case... I see scrollEvent on the console printed with every scroll I do on the page. How do you do this work?

```
if(document.body.classList){

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        console.log('scrollEvent');

        document.body.classList.remove('mobile-menu-open');

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the listener, once your class is removed from the `body`, that way it won't trigger any more when you scroll.

Here's the code:

```
var removeMenuClass = function() {
    document.body.classList.remove('mobile-menu-open');
    // remove the scroll listener
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', removeMenuClass, false);
}

// add the scroll listener
window.addEventListener('scroll', removeMenuClass, false);
```

If needed (let's say when your "mobile-menu" re-opens), you can re-attach the eventListener the same way.

Comment: Hey this seems to work, but only in the first scroll the class is removed. If I after open the navigation (So therefore the class is added again) and I scroll the class remains on the body. How can I create a sustainable code which checks if there is a class on the body, and if so remove it if there is a scroll. This works but strangely only one time.

Comment: It's written in my answer. You simply have to re-attach the event listener when the menu opens.

Answer (score 2):

Your if needs to check for that class

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    console.log('scrollEvent');

    // do the following only if it has the class
    if( document.body.classList.contains('mobile-menu-open') ) {

       document.body.classList.remove('mobile-menu-open');

    }

});
```

Comment: this answer would be perfect if you would also remove the listener once the class is removed :)

Comment: It sounds like the presence of the class is a trigger for the effect.  So I assume it can be re-added, in which case it's easier and probably more efficient to do a boolean check as opposed to add/remove the event handler every time.

Comment: I disagree, I guess I'll just add my own answer.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I'm learning a lot, The answer of Matt Pileggi works no matter how many times I open and close the menu. The answer of Skwal only works the first time but afterwards it does not work correctly.

Comment: If you have any links which could help me to learn about nativa javascript please do so.. I use at this moment: http://blog.romanliutikov.com/post/63383858003/how-to-forget-about-jquery-and-start-using-native, http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/